# netbeans jar build file not opening

Tags: java, opencv, netbeans

I have build my project using OpenCV. When I run my project through netbeans it runs fine.. but when I create its jar file via `Clean and Build` it doesn't open. 
it displays a message in output screen when it is build that is..

```
 To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
 java -jar "C:\Users\Rafi Abro\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebCam\dist\WebCam.jar"
```

I also tried to open my project through this command..

```
 java -jar WebCam.jar
```

but it displayed error below:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java2410 in
 java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at javaanpr.Main.main(Main.java:154)
```

please can anyone help me through out this problem..

Thanks

Comment: Have you added library to your project?

Comment: yes, OpenCV libraries are added

Comment: It means that libraries are added to class path of application jar and copied to lib folder in dist folder. Check this.

Comment: yes, there are libraries..

Comment: `System.loadLibrary` loads dynamic linking libray. Look at main which files loads and put them to dist.

Comment: Yes, in main method I use this line to load libraries... `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);`

Comment: And what Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME means? This library must be accessible to your application in current working dir.

Comment: `-Djava.library.path="C:\OpenCV\opencv\build\java\x86"` this is the path I have set in properties of my project as VM Path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have included VM option path in netbeans. and Netbeans Automatically calls it whenever it is executed.

now when you are trying to run command. i.e.

```
java -jar WebCam.jar
```

there is not path defined in command, thatsy you are getting that error..

try this command:

```
java -Djava.library.path="C:\OpenCV\opencv\build\java\x86" -jar WebCam.jar
```

hope this will help you.!